# Hide marker when my location get on it and show it again when i leave

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I put many markers in the map and already have my current location service provided so just want to hide the marker when my current location get on it and show it again when i leave , please be specific when you reply because I'm beginner "using Android Studio 1.5.1"

and this is my code which in MapsActivity.java

```
package com.example.karim.trysomething;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;



public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
       GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
       GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
       LocationListener {

public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();


private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

private GoogleMap mMap; 

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();




    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}


private void setUpMap() {



    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,  android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        String[] permissions,

        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();


    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);



    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();


    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();


    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);


    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));


    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!").snippet("Consider yourself located"));

    mMap.addMarker( new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(30.121683, 31.139405) )
            .title("Location")
            .snippet("ركنة المطحن")).showInfoWindow();     


}



@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {

            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before dive into code, you should define 'show' rule (logic). Simply, assume that you are in a center of circle with 250 meters radius everytime(pink marker). When your location changed, compare each marker position with your circle. Hide markers which is located in the circle, and show others.

[image][image]

Whenever your location changed, call a method like this

```
 // You have received new location and calling this method. 
 private void filterMarkers(LatLng myLocation){

    double myLatitude = myLocation.latitude;
    double myLongitude = myLocation.longitude;

    float[] distance = new float[2];
    for(int m = 0; m < mMarkers.size(); m++){
        Marker marker = mMarkers.get(m);
        LatLng position = marker.getPosition();
        double lat = position.latitude;
        double lon = position.longitude;

        /* distanceBetween method calculates the distance between two locations. 
           As i said above, you are in center of circle, means your location and 
           circle's location are same.

           Also you could look distanceBetween method
           http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double, double, double, double, float[])
         */
        Location.distanceBetween(lat, lon, myLatitude,
                myLongitude, distance);


        boolean inCircle = distance[0] <= mCircleRadius;
        // If marker is in circle hide it, otherwise show.
        marker.setVisible(!inCircle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to be carried out you need 
1.Compare current lat/long with the marker lat/long , do this in callback such as onMarkerRender and then change the current marker .
2. Retain the current marker later change the same the marker when you switch to next marker